# How to access the php variable from my external javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

How to access the php variable from my external javascript file.

this is my getting.js file

```
$(function(){

$(".search").keyup(function() 

{ 

var searchid = $(this).val();

var dataString = 'search='+ searchid;

if(searchid!='')

{

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "search.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    {
    $("#result").html(html).show();
    }
    });
}return false;    
});
```

and this my search.php file.

```
<?php

include('db.php');

if($_POST)
{

$q=$_POST['search'];

$sql_res=mysql_query("select id,name,email from detail where name like '%$q%' or email like '%$q%' order by id LIMIT 5");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_res))

{
$username=$row['name'];

$email=$row['email'];

$b_username='<strong>'.$q.'</strong>';

$b_email='<strong>'.$q.'</strong>';

$final_username = str_ireplace($q, $b_username, $username);

$final_email = str_ireplace($q, $b_email, $email);

?>
<div class="show" align="left">

<span class="name"><?php echo $username; ?></span>&nbsp;<br/><?php echo $email; ?><br/>

</div>

<?php

}

}

?>
```

I want to use `$username` in my `getting.js` file. how do I access this. Please let me know.

Comment: If this script is not rendered by php - you can't

Comment: Hi Bono, there are thousands of records. so i want to show these using for loop .

Comment: I think you miss difference between server and client code, and how they interact via http.

Comment: My preferred way is change your `search.php` to return `json` instead of html, and handle all received data in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I love php, which does not knew about html at all.

Try to change your search.php to return json instead of html:

```
...
$result = array('users' => array(), 'method'=>'search');
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_res))
{
  $result['users'][] = $row;
}
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
echo json_encode($result);
```

and handle all received data in javascript:

```
success: function(json) {
 var data = JSON.parse(json);
 console.log(data);
 // change DOM with new data etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I have found to export variables from PHP to JavaScript is to use a  snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var username = '<?=$username?>';</script>
```

This will set a new JavaScript variable named 'username' to the value of the PHP variable '$username' *at the time of page generation*. Place this snippet in the page header *above* where you include 'getting.js' and use the variable 'username' in 'getting.js'.

Note that

```
<?=$var?>
```

is a shortcut for

```
<?php echo $var ?>
```

Comment: Matt but i am using external js file i don't want to get it into index.php and there are thousands of records so how do i handle these.

Comment: In that case, either:
- Return a JSON object with a username and email property and construct the html in your success handler, or
- After inserting the html, use JQuery to get the contents of span.name

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of thing you could do for fetching PHP variables,

Create a hidden element for storing the php variable so it could be fetched from javascript

```
<input type="hidden" id="user-name" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
```

And you could fetch it in Javascript by simply using

```
var userName = $("#user-name").val();
```

Or , you could define a javascript variable in your search.php file as ,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var username = '<?php echo $username; ?>';
</script>
```

And As you have mentioned above, you can simply use ,

```
<span class="name"><?php echo $username; ?></span>
```

And in JavaScript ,

```
$(".name").val();
```

for fetching userName.